# Alfred is annoyed with finder

Tags: finder, finder-tag, alfred

Alfred is having an issue with Finder. When I do an Alfred search for finder a window will appear provided I had previously closed it. If I have a finder window open in another desktop, Alfred will only change the top grey bar to the 'finder' version, but won't change desktop to the finder window, nor produce a new finder window.

I have tried reinstalling alfred with no luck, and this issue has survived the most recent macOS update.

Comment: I have a theory that this is part of a larger 'breakage' in Finder in recent OSes. Test: Close all Finder windows, then change Spaces so you're in Desktop 1. Right click Finder in the dock & set to 'Options>This Desktop' Open one Finder window on that Space. Switch to an app on any other space, then click outside that on any visible part of your desktop background. It *ought* to flick back to Space 1 with your Finder window frontmost. These days, it doesn't.

Comment: Any idea on a fix? From what I can tell not many people are having this issue.

Comment: I've had the 'return to Space 1' issue intermittently since about High Sierra. From Mojave it't become permanent. Short of a full reinstall from scratch to test, idk what else to suggest.